# Referring to rule style in expression string builder in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, rule-based

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover.

I've got a rule-styled polygon layer `cuadric_cabañ`. Rules are:

```
overlay_intersects(layer:='habitat_caba',filter:=(CODIIGE=210 OR CODIIGE=320))
overlay_intersects(layer:='habitat_caba',filter:=(CODIIGE=330)
```

Both shapefiles are available in [this link](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/fjQc/dQBrZLbLq)

Both rules have their own label `RABILARGA` and `COGUJADA`(see image) and, using the corresponding button, I've obtained their simple statistics:

[image]

In the print composer I've placed a legend that I want it to read

```
RABILARGA (n = 294)
COGUJADA (n = 297)
```

Is it possible that those figures (294 and 297) could be invoked directly for the statistics of the rule?

Alternatively, I have built a code that works in an independent text box but, surprisingly, not within the legend description for that class:

```
'n = ' || aggregate(layer:= 'cuadric_cabañ',
aggregate:='count',
expression:='COD1X1',
filter:=overlay_intersects(layer:= 'habitat_caba', filter:=CODIIGE=330))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the legend item properties, simply uncheck `Auto update` and then click `Show feature count for each class of vector layer`:

*Screenshots: layer p1 is styled in yellor or orange depending on how many intersecting polygons from the red layer (p2) there are:*
[image]

[image]

*You can add further text by clicking `Edit selected item properties` (pen icon) and adding text. However, the format with the square brackets is fixed, you can't change it (at least not here):*
[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the answer: `Show feature count for each class of vector layer`. However, can this count text style be edited? E.g. to show [n = 5] instead of simply [5]

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a way to display it on your main maps legend, right click your layer in the layer-panel and select "show feature count":

[image]